# Having issue with event.Preventdefault

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 2 links in my component one to render product detail and another to generate a compare card.

The fetch is invoked in 2 different functions which need an item id to be passed as a parameter. If I call it as a normal function,(onClickProductDetail) the fetch is running multiple times on rendering. SO modified it so that I can call event.preventDefault( OnCLickCOmpareDetails) but then the ROuter is not rendering the child component at all

I tried 2 different ways to handle the OnClick

```
handleClickProductDetail (product_id) {
     //event.preventDefault();
     console.log('product_id inside handleClickProductDetail', product_id)
    this.props.fetchProductDetails(product_id);
  }


 handleClickCompareDetail (event,product_id) {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log('product_id inside handleClickCompareDetail', product_id)
    this.props.fetchCompareDetails(product_id);
 }

  render() {
      //console.log("Prop-items",this.props.items)
      if(this.props.items === undefined ){
            return <center> <p>&nbsp;</p> Please enter a string value to search for items </center>
         }
        return (
        <div>
            <table>
              {this.props.items.map((item, index) => (

                  <td>
                      <p> &nbsp;</p>
                      <p></p>
                      <p>  <img src={item.product_image}/></p>
                       <p>{item.product_title}</p>

                       <HashRouter>
                          <p><Link to={`/Compare/${item.product_id}`} component={CompareCard} onClick={(event)=>this.handleClickCompareDetail(event,item.product_id)}> Compare Prices </Link></p>
                          <p><Link to={`/${item.product_id}`} component={ProductDetail} onClick={this.handleClickProductDetail(item.product_id)}> Product Details </Link></p>
                          <Route exact path={`/Compare/${item.product_id}`} render={()=><CompareCard compare_detail={this.props.compareDetails.data.stores}/>}/>

                          <Route exact path={`/${item.product_id}`} render={()=><ProductDetail product_detail={this.props.productDetails.data.main_specs}/>}/>

                        </HashRouter>
                 </td>


            ))}
            </table>

        </div>
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><Link to={`/${item.product_id}`} component={ProductDetail} onClick={this.handleClickProductDetail(item.product_id)}> Product Details </Link></p>
```

In the above element's `onClick` event, you have actually invoked the `handleClickProductDetail` function without defining it as a hander. So it will be invoked at the rendering.

Change it to below (similar to what you have done in **Compare Prices** link) and there is no need for `event.preventDefault();`.

```
<p><Link to={`/${item.product_id}`} component={ProductDetail} onClick={(event)=>this.handleClickProductDetail(item.product_id)}> Product Details </Link></p>
```

---

In summary, you have defined the `onClick` as,

```
onClick={this.handleClickProductDetail(item.product_id)}
```

but it should be,

```
onClick={(event)=>this.handleClickProductDetail(item.product_id)}
```

Comment: That's a different issue in the next line where you define `compare_detail={this.props.compareDetails.data.stores}`. Better to check your input props and fix it.

Comment: however, it is related- so when i have a plain function without the handler- it works but the fetch runs multiple times- when i put in the handler it seems to be not invkoing th efftch at all- not sure whare the problem is